# Using 'multiprocessing' libary in Python 3 for PostgreSQL queries

Tags: python, postgresql, concurrency, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing

I'm trying to write a Python script to read query data from my database into pandas dataframes.

I have simplified the code significantly to test the effectiveness of using the multiprocessing library in order to parallelize running the queries since running a query including all of the information I want to collect takes several minutes.

However, using Pool from multiprocessing is not the most effective. (In fact, no difference in performance occurred when running the script). Is there a more effective approach to run queries concurrently in PostgreSQL?

Any advice would be awesome!

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa
from multiprocessing import Pool

engine = sa.create_engine("<database info>")

def run_query(query):
    print(query)
    data_frame = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=len(queries))
    pool.map(run_query, queries)
```

Comment: Reading from a database is usually an I/O-bound task and no amount of multiprocessing will help you. (In some rare circumstances you might be able to parallelize in order to better utilize the *server's* CPU resources if the query is CPU-bound on the server.) Instead, you should focus on how you can optimize your query, including adding indices or use bulk loading capabilities.

Comment: can you please elaborate on the latter? it is connected to aws redshift if that helps

Comment: Okay Redshift is a little different from PostgreSQL, in that it has its own bulk loading functionality called [unloading](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Unloading_tables.html). You'll need to include your schema as well as your query in order to get tips on how to optimize your query.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is efficient but you can use worker and producers scheme. Basically you define a multiprocessing Q and the producer process adds something into the Q. The Worker listens to the Q and starts working as soon some information is put into the Q.

Here is a good example.

http://danielhnyk.cz/python-producers-queue-consumed-by-workers/

The problem you have with Multiprocessing is that you have to take care about shared data and also the time to schedule the processes must be taken into account which makes the Multiprocessing in Python not very usable for small tasks. However, If you do that tasks very often or you create the process once and just run the tasks when there is one you get a benefit.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a small task. Each query returns 100K+ rows of data with over 15 columns.